# How to use a forLoop instead of $.each

Tags: jquery, json, for-loop

This should be an easy one, I just can't find an answer doing searches.
I have an image gallery with about 400 images that are filtered on different data.
I'm using jquery to read JSON data. It loops thru the data to create the image and captions.
Everything works correctly but it is filtering VERY slowly. Everything I have read says to use a for loop instead of $.each to speed up the looping.
Problem is I have not used a for loop before and can't seem to get the code right (I am not a jquery expert obviously). This is the code I am using that works using $.each - how do I replace this with a forLoop?

```
var data = [
{"id":7,"width":54,"colorNumber":91380,"collection":"Adelle","colorName":"Agate","colorRange":"Green/teal","content":"material content goes here","repeat":"repeat","category":"category","origin":"origin"},
{"id":45,"width":54,"colorNumber":91381,"collection":"Adelle","colorName":"Emerald","colorRange":"yellow/gold/orange/red","content":"material content goes here","repeat":"repeat","category":"category","origin":"origin"},
{"id":13,"width":54,"colorNumber":93022,"collection":"Adromeda","colorName":"Galaxy","colorRange":"white/cream","content":"material content goes here","repeat":"repeat","category":"category","origin":"origin"}
```

......etc

```
];
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    $('#images').append(
"<li data-id='" + obj.colorNumber + "' data-type='" + obj.colorRange + "' id='image" + obj.colorNumber +"'>"
+
....etc
```

Comment: Post your attempted solution. Also, your problem isn't going to be the loop, the problem will be that you're calling `$('#...')` 400 times inside the loop, and appending to that element 400 times inside the loop. Try building a single HTML fragment and appending the *entire* thing in *one call* after the loop

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried each of the suggestions given but am not seeing any improvement in the speed which leads me to believe it is simply the number and size of the images I am loading. I am using the Quicksand.js plugin for the filtering. I'm wondering if the fact that it creates a duplicate set of data when filtering is also a problem. Any suggestions on another approach?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<img id='image' src='https://jquery.org/resources/members/wordpress.png'/>
```

**JS**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
var data = [
    {
        "id":7,
        "width":54,
        "colorNumber":91380,
        "collection":"Adelle",
        "colorName":"Agate",
        "colorRange":"Green/teal",
        "content":"material content goes here",
        "repeat":"repeat",
        "category":"category",
        "origin":"origin"
    },
    {"id":45,"width":54,"colorNumber":91381,"collection":"Adelle","colorName":"Emerald","colorRange":"yellow/gold/orange/red","content":    "material content goes here","repeat":"repeat","category":"category","origin":"origin"},
    {"id":13,"width":54,"colorNumber":93022,"collection":"Adromeda","colorName":"Galaxy","colorRange":"white/cream","content":"material content goes here","repeat":"repeat","category":"category","origin":"origin"}];

var html = '<br/><ul>';
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  html += "<li data-id='" + data[i].colorNumber + "' data-type='" + data[i].colorRange + "' id='image" + data[i].colorNumber +"'>" + data[i].colorName + '</li>';
}
$('#image').after(html+'</ul>');
});//]]> 
</script>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o9vhnc2s/)**